# copy Chinese file source to destination in java

Tags: java

copying Chinese file in java using this code . but the destination file contains question mark (?) instead of Chinese character . is there any way in java to achieve this functionality..

```
 File source = new File("H:\\work-temp\\file");
 File dest = new File("H:\\work-temp\\file2");
try {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have already been discussed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377756/write-chinese-characters-from-one-file-to-another

Answer (score 0):

You are miss the extension of files for ex: `file.txt` and `file2.txt`:

```
   File source = new File("H:\\work-temp\\file.txt");
   File dest = new File("H:\\work-temp\\file2.txt");
```

For coping use this:

```
  FileChannel inputChannel = null;
  FileChannel outputChannel = null;
  try{
    inputChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
    outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
    outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
} finally {
    inputChannel.close();
    outputChannel.close();
}
```

For more info go to this  [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while copying a file, the destination should be a folder not file... so please change `File dest = new File("H:\\work-temp\\file2");` to `File dest = new File("H:\\work-temp");`

Next you should use `FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);` instead `FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);`

Comment: but this  function convert Chinese language into ? .

Comment: It simply copies the source file into destination folder... I didn't try it with chinese text.. I think it should work..

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the JDK 7 [`Files.copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream)) methods. They create a binary copy of your file.

Comment: can you provide me any example.